# Getting user profile in angular after user logged in

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication, angular-ui-router, angular-promise

In my application each user has a specific profile, I have created a service to hold this profile named `currentUser`.

I use the properties of this profile to render my the header of site and make further api calls.

the problems is that when should I fill this `currentProfile` service?

There are a few options:

1 - after login promise is resolved:

```
authService.login(username, pass)
    .then(function(response) {
        userService.getProfile()
            .then(function(profile){
                currentUser.setProfile(profile);
                $state.go('dashboard');
            });
    });
```

the main problem with this approach is that if a user is in this url `/main/list` and refreshes the page, `currentUser` gets emptied.

2 - using ui-router `deferIntercept` and `urlRouter.sync()` and `$urlRouter.listen()` like [here](https://ui-router.github.io/docs/0.3.1/#/api/ui.router.router.$urlRouterProvider) , but the main problem with this approach is that my header directive and controller gets executed before (or during) event handler of `$locationChangeStart` and `currentUser` is not filled yet.

How can I achieve my desried effect? any idea is appreceated!

**Edit**: I don't want to rely on localStorage or cookie or ....

Comment: After login populate profile into localStorage or cookie, fetch it back upon refresh. Clear it on logout

Comment: @SaneeshB I don't want to use these storages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ui-router , it has a resolve property which ensures data is loaded before the application continues.

```js
$stateProvider
        .state('main.list', {
            url: "/main/list",
            templateUrl: "views/custom/index.html",
            controller:MainController,
            resolve: {
                loginUser : function($q){
                  //load data or whatever
                   return loadData();
                }
            }
        })
```

Comment: what you say means that i should add an extra resolve property to each of my application states , correct me if I am wrong. but the nature of `currentUser` is different from a resolve property. it is a global service that can be used in every where in my app, and in each use case it should be filled.

Comment: resolve is needed only if you have to populate the current user. You dont have to add it to all the states have an abstract state and then add it to that so all the children under it will inherit the same resolve. also currentUser being a global service has nothing to do with this. you want a service to be filled when the user hits a specific URL or any other condition, this service can be filled from anywhere else in the app as well.

Comment: thanks man, seems your solution is working just fine, what the use of `$q` ? It seems to me redundant.

Comment: yeah.. $q is redundant XD